# Does not preserve the value of cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Posted CellEditor.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;

public class UserCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor 
                            implements TableCellEditor {

    JComponent component = new JTextField();

    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return ((JTextField) component).getText();
    }

    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, 
            Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        ((JTextField) component).setText((String) value);
        return component;
    }
}
```

Then I call table method in such way:

```
UserTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(new UserCellEditor());
```

The cell is being edited, but the result by pressing the `Enter` key or move to another cell is not stored, it returns the original value.

Where am I wrong or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looks OK, similar to code seen, for example, in exampledepot.com, perhaps there is an error in the table code?

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect.

Comment: In my model table has not been overridden method setValueAt :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are editing the value in a local `JTextField`, while your data model is subsequently returning the unchanged value when editing is complete. Your editor needs to update your model, as suggested in this [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table).

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting a `CustomTableCellEditor` for a column, that column must be updated in the `setValueAt(Object o, int row, int column)` of the corresponding TableModel, if you don't do that the new value is never updated. By the way if you define your `CustomTableCellEditor` this way:

`public class CustomTableCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor`

You won't need to fire events by yourself.